# Ajax will not load when FTP is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ftp

I'm just trying to get the hang of using Ajax with FTP so it'll load my changes in real-time. However, not matter how I change the code it just won't do what i want it to and to my knowledge the code itself seems fine...All it's suppose to do is alert the contents of my test.html file ("this is some content") when I load it into the ftp.
    
    
    
    Learning JQuery

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/jquery.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Asyncronous Javascript And XML </h1>

<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Ajax:

```
$.get("test.html", function(data) {
alert(data);
});
```

Comment: Uhm, woot, ajax with FTP how exactly ?

Comment: I guess to me more specific the ftp really isn't the issue because not matter if i refresh the page it still won't run the ajax. I just want the Ajax code to alert the contents of my test.html file when I load the page

Comment: But FTP, as in File Transfer Protocol, how are you using that to open .html pages? You're sure you shouldn't just download WAMP or something ?

Comment: I have free web hosting at the moment so i'm just using the ftp to upload files to that server and manually typing my url into chrome to load the content

Comment: It has no sense. You upload your files through ftp which has no relation with what (I think) you want to do. Ajax and FTP have no relation. If you want to load `test.html`, you are doing it well. http://jsfiddle.net/ox6mfv4b/

Comment: I figured it out it was an extremely simple fix. I was using the wrong domain name so it wasn't even including that part of the code